# iphone - how to let the user listen to music while tracking his sport

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm new to iOS development. I'm building a sport tracker app for iPhone ,which would track the amount of distance walked by the user,and  their speed with Location data/GPS. With the app the user can access the iPhone's music player, and choose a song then back to  the application.

What sort of APIs would I use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use: `MPMusicPlayerController`

With that class you can integrate music from the master music library into your application. You should also use the following category for your own sounds in your application so they don't stop the music.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
```

By registering for the above sound category you can ensure your sound effects don't pause or interrupt the music.

From the docs:

*Use an MPMusicPlayerController object, or music player, to play media items from the device iPod library. There are two types of music player:
The application music player plays music locally within your app. It is not aware of the iPod app’s now-playing item, nor does it affect the iPod state.
The iPod music player employs the built-in iPod app on your behalf. On instantiation, it takes on the current iPod app state, such as the identification of the now-playing item. If a user switches away from your app while music is playing, that music continues to play. The iPod app then has your music player’s most recently-set repeat mode, shuffle mode, playback state, and now-playing item.*

Let me know if you need any further help,

Comment: could ypu provide me a link to do that :( im really lost

Comment: I'll come back to you soon

Comment: @user2987058 Ok my friend, which piece are you having trouble with? Can you post code on your question?